# How to set permalink for post in blogger using Python gdata library

Tags: python, gdata, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I am trying to create a new post with a given permalink using gdata.blogger, but it does not work. After the usual fandango to log in, I use the following code:

```
    entry = gdata.blogger.BlogPostEntry()
    entry.title = atom.Title(title_type="xhtml", text=title)
    entry.content = atom.Content(content_type="html", text=content)

    # We have to use the GData function since we need to add the permalink
    blog_id = self.__blog.GetSelfLink().href.split('/')[-1]
    blog_uri = '/feeds/%s/posts/default' % blog_id

    url_params = {
        'path': permalink,
    }
    logging.info("Publishing blog '%s' using permalink '%s'", title, permalink)

    self.__blog_ws.Post(
        entry, blog_uri, url_params=url_params,
        converter=gdata.blogger.BlogPostEntryFromString)
```

Despite providing an explicit path, it uses part of the title for creating the link.

Is providing an alternate link for the entry the solution (I'm not very familiar with the Atom format), and in that case, how do you do that?